# Global.asax.cs Custom Date Formatting Across Website

Tags: c#, webforms, date-format

I am developing a ASP.NET C# Webforms website with MySQL as the database supplying dates in its standard date format.

How can I add a **custom date** format to the Global.asax.cs file like the follow (non-working code):

```
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Threading;

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
      CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();

      //Will make all dates of the format similar to 3/14/13 12:9 AM/PM 
      newCulture.DateTimeFormat = "M/d/yy h:m tt";

      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimeFormat` property is actually an object of type `DateTimeFormatInfo` with lots of different properties.  Try this:

```
CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "M/d/yy";
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "h:m tt";
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "M/d/yy";
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "h:m tt";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
```

Now if you just do something like this in your ASP.Net code:

```
<%= DateTime.Now %>
```

It should pick up on the format from your culture.  Of course, it could easily be overridden:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("ss:mm:HH dd/MM/yyyy") %>   // backwards!
```

You can't do anything to prevent that.  All you can do is change the defaults.

The short and long patterns are probably the only ones you need to change.  The default (general) pattern is constructed from these.

Comment: Why do you need to call `CurrentCulture.Clone()` rather than simply using `CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = ""`, etc?